# Hyperlinks not working on xs screens in Bootstrap v3.3.1

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, hyperlink

Help please, I cannot think of a reason why my hyperlinks don't show on the smallest screens (xs) while they do show and work on other screen sizes. It is likely to be a problem related to the way I've written my code - when I take offline my custom css file (https://balmainmassage.com.au/2015/css/2015.css) my links still don't work, while they do when I take offline bootstrap.min.css. I have NOT modified the bootstrap file.

I have this problem on all pages based on the template 2015.dwt which lives in the `Templates` folder in the `public_html` folder. An example of a page based on this template is at https://balmainmassage.com.au/2015/january_specials.html. It works at all screen sizes except xs.

However, note that - in the same files - the **navigation hyperlinks designed for the xs screen** (different than for the other screen sizes, you'll find them after the line `<!-- page body ends here, menu and footer start -->`) **DO WORK**.

Older pages in the site not based on bootstrap do work - of course, although they are not responsive.
Really puzzled... Thanks for your help!

Claudio

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your div with class `nav nav-pills` is overlapping your div with the class `col-xs-12`  which contains the hyperlinks when the page size is reduced, what you have to do now is to add `z-index : 1` to your `col-xs-12` class like so :

```
.col-xs-12 {
  z-index: 1;
}
```

I suggest that you add another class name to your `col-xs-12` class to avoid overriding `bootstrap css` :

```
<div class="col-xs-12 MyClassName"> 
.MyClassName {
  z-index: 1;
}
```

Comment: Ze you saved my life, had to go live with this today